# With MySQL, why is this date query showing incorrect results?

Tags: mysql

Sample table:

```
id | foreign_key_id | timestamp           | amt |
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 223344         | 2018-06-01 09:22:31 | 3
2  | 233445         | 2018-06-15 23:22:31 | 2
2  | 233445         | 2018-06-30 23:22:31 | 5
3  | 334455         | 2018-07-01 12:22:31 | 1
3  | 334455         | 2018-07-15 12:22:31 | 1
4  | 344556         | 2018-07-31 20:22:31 | 2
```

And what I want is a grouped result of the total of `amt` per month, something like,

```
year | month | total_amt
------------------------
2018 |     6 |       10
2018 |     7 |        4
```

Which I thought would be easily enough achieved with a query like,

```
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) year, MONTH(timestamp) month, SUM(amt) total_amt
FROM sample_table
WHERE timestamp >= '2018-06-01'
AND timestamp <= '2018-07-31'
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp)
```

Unfortunately, the result of this query is incorrect,

```
year | month | total_amt
------------------------
2018 |     6 |       10
2018 |     7 |        2
```

The amount for June is correct, but July is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a misunderstanding of what *is* timestamp here, and then what *is* the compared string.

In the timestamp is a date-time object, which has both a date part, and a time part.  The string used in the query is *just* the date part, without the time part, so when MySQL is doing its thing, it basically "zeroes out" the rest of the date.

So when the query is

```
...
AND timestamp <= '2018-07-31'
```

It basically turns into,

```
...
AND timestamp <= '2018-07-31 00:00:00'
```

And when you dump the row that isn't matched with the query,

```
...
AND '2018-07-31 20:22:31' <= '2018-07-31 00:00:00'
```

Whether it's date comparison, or even simple string comparison, the missing row's timestamp is *not* less or equal to the date passed in, it is definitely more.

You've a few options to fix this, create a full date-time object in the comparison, with the "fullest" of times,

```
...
AND timestamp <= '2018-07-31 23:59:59'
```

Change the operator to less-than the next date,

```
...
AND timestamp < '2018-08-01'
```

Or convert the timestamp from a date-time object to a date one,

```
...
AND DATE(timestamp) <= '2018-07-31'
```

All work, though I'm not sure about which is the best one performance / speed wise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) year, MONTH(timestamp) month, SUM(amt) total_amt
FROM sample_table
WHERE timestamp >= '2018-06-01'
AND timestamp < '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will work:**

```
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) year, MONTH(timestamp) month, SUM(amt) total_amt
FROM sample_table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= '2018-06-01'
AND DATE(timestamp) <= '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);
```

OR

```
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) year, MONTH(timestamp) month, SUM(amt) total_amt
FROM sample_table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);
```

Comment: Properly indexed, note that `timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-01 00:00:00'` would be more efficient